# serverless deploy comando nao encontrado mesmo após a instalação

Tags: python, npm, amazon-aws

Instalei o serverless via npm, porem diz que o comando serverless e serverless deploy não existem,nem mesmo serverles -v, como se não tivesse instalado via npm.

Comment: Você precisa instalar globalmente, com -g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você instalou o serverless utilizando o -g?

`npm install -g serverless`

**Se sim**:

Verifique se a instalação do node está no seu $PATH.

`echo $PATH`

**Se não**:

Se você instalou o serverless direto no seu projeto Python, tente rodar:

`./node_modules/.bin/serverless -v`

Comment: Obrigado amigo, o problema era que o node não estava no $PATH.